# How to remove only files created before a specific date and time

Tags: bash, scripts, files, rm, date

l would like to remove from my directory files which have been created before 04/29/2018 at 4:00 pm.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux doesn't keep record of creation time, there are only 3 time records for files: last access, last modification of contents and last modification of the inode. So you are left with 3 options:

To delete all files modified before 04/29/2018 at 4:00 pm:

```
find . -type f ! -newermt '04/29/2018 16:00:00' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

To delete all files accessed before 04/29/2018 at 4:00 pm:

```
find . -type f ! -newerat '04/29/2018 16:00:00' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

To delete all files which had their permission changed before 04/29/2018 at 4:00 pm:

```
find . -type f ! -newerct '04/29/2018 16:00:00' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You probably wouldn't want to run the above commands as `root`, and remember to **backup** any important files.

### Important note!

You should treat date values with caution. Even though I did a complete format to my hard drive last month, I have some files in my home directory dating back to 2014!

Sources: [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20464)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158235)[[3]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/)

Comment: `find` also has the `-delete` option which you can use instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;`, this saves you the call of `rm` for every single match. Both are to handle with great care: 1) Always have a backup at hand. 2) First print the matches, i.e. execute `find` without any `-delete` or `-exec` options. 3) Check very carefully! 4) Run `find` with `-delete`.

Comment: A safer alternative for `-exec` in this context is `-ok`, which asks for every match – or one can make `rm` ask with `-exec rm -i {} \;`. Unless you have a *lot* of files/directories to delete, `-exec … {} +` will work as well and be faster.

Comment: `Linux doesn't keep record of creation time`. That's not true, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file/92748