# How to delete all files based on year in unix?

Tags: command-line

I need to delete all files in a directory that were created in 2018. What command can I use to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove only files created before a specific date and time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029799/how-to-remove-only-files-created-before-a-specific-date-and-time)

Comment: @guiverc OP only wants to deleted files in 2018. Duplicate candidate would also delete files in 2017.

Comment: Yeah I'd likely do it using -mtime (specified twice so start/end, and manually getting the number of days back which is messy)

Comment: **The duplicate is dangerous to execute for OP!**  *Voted to leave open!*  **Hawa** If your question would be closed, leave a comment @Fabby and I'll come back and start the reopen process.  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` `-newermt` option:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -newermt 2018-01-01 ! -newermt 2019-01-01 -print
```

or for less thinking:

```
y=2018
find /path/to/directory -type f -newermt $y-01-01 ! -newermt $((y+1))-01-01 -print
```

Change `-print` to `-delete` if you're happy with the result.

Comment: nice, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678491 and `-mtime` can be useful too to delete older than n days (365 for a year !-)

Answer (score 1):

A script like this:

```
DIR="$1"
for f in "$DIR"/*
do
    FileDate=$(stat -c %y "$f")
    if [[ "${FileDate:0:4}" = "2018" ]] ; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

Call the script and pass the directory name, eg `kill2018 /home/me/Documents`

Comment: what if i want it in command. I try to use this command "find . -type f -ctime +365 -ls" but only show past one year. How can i only select for 2018?

Comment: You can do that by using the script above instead of what you're trying to do @Hawa

Comment: @Hawa Another answer has been posted using the `find` command which does that.